# Is it possible to autogenerate GlobalKey?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a list of widgets which I am using GlobalKeys to monitor their position and state. However, I would like to programatically generate them as manually is tedious and doesn't seem like the write approach.

```
Is it possible in flutter to generate GlobalKey names dynamically?
```

It's been a few hours of trial and error and the closest I can was a Map, however I still had to manually create all the GlobalKeys, which in my case is quite a few.

Please tell me there is a better way without having to change the way I manage my state.

Comment: Can you show how you are creating a list of widgets?

Comment: Sounds like you are falling for the XY problem. Why do you need GlobalKeys to begin with?

Comment: I'm tracking the location of a number of widgets as the user drags them around the screen and checking if their rectangles interects with others, imagine chess pieces on a board, but not as complicated, is global keys not the right approach? Would bloc be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here was no, you can't.  I changed to a bloc based state management and it is working great.